# UnrecognizedClientException in AWS fargate

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I try to deploy a fargate container in AWS ECS. But I get the following error

```
error getting rds cred staging/tas: 
{
    "message": "The security token included in the request is invalid",
    "code": "UnrecognizedClientException",
    "time": "2020-06-07T06:10:17.324Z",
    "requestId": "5a3287f8-8c7b-49f9-b346-9239840f05bd",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 7.012616197026311
}
```

as I am using the fargate, the next thing is I check the task role and the task execution role. They use the same IAM which uses the AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

as requested i add in the task definition

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws-cn:iam::xxxyyyeeezzz:role/tas-common-resource-ECSTaskExecutionRole-ZEATKLAUUDV8",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": [],
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": [],
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "TASStagingLogs",
          "awslogs-region": "cn-north-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "web-app-staging"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8000
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "npm",
        "start"
      ],
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "NODE_ENV",
          "value": "staging"
        },
        {
          "name": "RDS_SECRET_NAME",
          "value": "staging/tas"
        }
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": [],
      "dnsServers": [],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": [],
      "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "xxxyyyeeezzz.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/tas/master-server",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": [],
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": [],
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": {},
      "systemControls": [],
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "web-app"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "4096",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws-cn:iam::xxxyyyeeezzz:role/tas-common-resource-ECSTaskExecutionRole-ZEATKLAUUDV8",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws-cn:ecs:cn-north-1:xxxyyyeeezzz:task-definition/master-web-staging-WebTaskDef-ZE50JXHI06U1:1",
  "family": "master-web-staging-WebTaskDef-ZE50JXHI06U1",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "2048",
  "revision": 1,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

But it has read access to all resources in secretsmanager, so i wonder what could have gone wrong. Please help. thanks

Comment: It seems the Task role is not set properly, can you exec into the container and run this command to confirm the credential endpoint is set: 
$ curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI

Comment: Also check this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=273767

Comment: @shariqmaws does that work in china AWS?

Comment: it says `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`

Comment: Please share your task definition in the question.

Comment: @shariqmaws added

Comment: Taskdef looks ok, is it possible there is some hardcoded credentials in the container? E.g. run the container locally and see if there is some files under ~/.aws/. There may be stale credentials stored that the SDK is using inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem has been fixed. The issue is that the region is wrong. It is hardcoded in the app as ap-southeast-1 but the app was deployed in cn-north-1